# Java Lambda picking off stderr and stdout of shell command

Tags: java, serverless

I'm a completely unqualified Java programmer (and that's giving me more credit than I deserve) but while working on a AWS lambda driven backend I ran into the need to run a JAVA app from the command line and while I'm entirely comfortable executing shell scripts within a NodeJS container I'm completely out of my depth with JAVA. I've looked for helpful instruction and just haven't found what I'm looking for. Was hoping someone could give me a pointer on:

1. Using `vs-code` as an editor, how would I make the amazonaws runtime libraries available to my code? I have statements like:

   ```
     import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
     import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
   ```

   which when at compile time complain that the packages don't exist. Fair enough, pretty sure they do *not* but I'm not sure how to include them. I know this is basic stuff.
2. I found some code which seems to provide a good starting point for executing shell commands and then picking up *stdin* and *stdout* but when I replaced the demo example of "**ps -ef**" with "**ls**" I immediately found that complained about not having a current working directory set. How can I get the **cwd** set and can I use relative referencing?

   Below is the code snippet that I was hoping to leverage (I would be replacing the shell command with a Java executable I've been provided and stdout and stdin would be sent back using Lambda callback rather than the `println` done here.

   ```
   public static void main(String args[]) {

     String s = null;

     try {

       // run the Unix "ps -ef" command
       // using the Runtime exec method:
       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -ef");

       BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

       BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

       // read the output from the command
       System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
       while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(s);
       }

       // read any errors from the attempted command
       System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
       while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(s);
       }

       System.exit(0);
     } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
       e.printStackTrace();
       System.exit(-1);
     }
   }
   ```

---

When I ran the demo project `gs-spring-boot` I got the following errors from vs-code output window (specifically from the Language Support Tools output):

[Error - 11:57:10 AM] Feb 27, 2018, 11:57:05 AM Initialization failed 
Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-bin.zip'.
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.create(DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.java:106)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:83)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:50)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultProjectConnection.getModel(DefaultProjectConnection.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.newModelBuilder(ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchModel(DefaultModelProvider.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.supportsCompositeBuilds(DefaultModelProvider.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchModels(DefaultModelProvider.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchEclipseGradleProjects(DefaultModelProvider.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.GradleProjectImporter.startSynchronization(GradleProjectImporter.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.GradleProjectImporter.importDir(GradleProjectImporter.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.GradleProjectImporter.lambda$0(GradleProjectImporter.java:89)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1380)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.GradleProjectImporter.importToWorkspace(GradleProjectImporter.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.ProjectsManager.importProjects(ProjectsManager.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.ProjectsManager.access$1(ProjectsManager.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.ProjectsManager$1.run(ProjectsManager.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2214)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2241)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5676)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5633)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.ProjectsManager.initializeProjects(ProjectsManager.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.InitHandler$1.runInWorkspace(InitHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:60)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type FileWatcherFactory using GlobalScopeServices.createFileWatcherFactory().
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:741)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:695)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:537)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:577)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:705)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:694)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:537)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:577)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:705)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:694)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:537)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:577)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.doGet(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:393)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:374)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.initializeServices(DefaultConnection.java:83)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.configure(DefaultConnection.java:70)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractPost12ConsumerConnection.configure(AbstractPost12ConsumerConnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.createConnection(DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.java:111)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.create(DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.java:89)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:101)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:83)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '9.0.4'.
    at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.filewatch.DefaultFileWatcherFactory.(DefaultFileWatcherFactory.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.GlobalScopeServices.createFileWatcherFactory(GlobalScopeServices.java:288)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.invoke(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:426)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.access$1200(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:739)
    ... 32 more

Comment: On Question 2: Where are you running the program? More details on the error and environment would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I’m so over my head I wasn’t even sure how to give good context. :p  I’m using the Serverless framework to deploy a number of micro-services. All the others are in NodeJS but for now I just put the JAVA file in the `/src` directory along with the TS/JS files. Then as part of my build script I run `javac src/*.java -d lib/`. In the `serverless.yml` file I’m pointing to the handler as being `apple.itms::handler` where “apple” is the name of the package (as I have defined in the top line of my source file ... notably with a vs-code warning saying it expected package “”). Does that help?

Comment: btw, I suspect I MUST be missing something in the config to inform the JAVA system where to find the Java class file. I had originally thought I should include “lib.apple” or something like that to get me into the lib directory but really just knocking around in the dark.

Comment: You should try to run it on your local development environment first. If you are developing on a Windows PC, then the above code should run with "dir" instead of "ls". On a Mac or Ubuntu the "ls" should run fine and you should see the output. Once it is running fine on your local with the other changes you are targeting to make, then you can keep the way you are doing it as long as it is a single java source file. Otherwise you can also pack it as a Jar as you did for question 1.

Comment: I’m on a mac. The problem sounded more like it needed to be told in what directory to start in. I did run `ps -ef` and that worked fine so shelling out is working. Also the testing I’m doing **is** local. I haven’t been so brave as to deploy it yet. :p

Comment: Sorry, my bad. When we run a java program, the directory from which it ran becomes the working directory and we can have relative paths from this working directory.

Comment: That’s what I’m used to in NodeJS and what I was expecting. Do you shell out using a different API?